# Raid 0 - Why am I constantly losing data?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, data-recovery, raid

I have a Mediasonic 4 bay drive enclosure like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003X26VV4) with four 3TB Toshiba HDD's attached to my hackintosh machine.

The drives are in a RAID 0 configuration setup with Disk Utility. I've had this setup now for several months and it seems to be very unreliable in terms of actual data loss.

I'm constantly reading and writing large files and often they just disappear from the folders they are in. Other times the drive will become totally unresponsive and I will have to use [Drive Genius](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/drive_genius.php) to repair it.

Usually when I un-mount/re-mount the drive, the lost+found folder will appear with some data that was lost. I'm hoping some of you might have suggestions for me as to possible causes and solutions?

Comment: What are the partitions formatted in?

Comment: Mac OS Extended (journaled)

Comment: You are likely better off asking in the mediasonic forums or even contacting the company directly: http://forum.mediasonic.ca

Answer (score 3):

You do know that RAID 0 is only striping and not only provides no redundancy, but increases the risk of data loss as the failure of any single drive can mean the loss of the entire storage pool? RAID 0 is only for increasing read and write speeds, for example for video editing.

You need at least RAID 1 or 5 for redundancy.

That being said, if you're losing data, one of the drives may be bad our you have a controller problem. I'd resolve that before moving to a higher RAID level.